# Is there a way to find a class that dissapeared after refractoring to another package?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, package, definition, launcher

I have recently Refractored a Launcher.java class in Intellij to another package but only the Launcher.class path was moved and the .java dissapeared.
I have moved the .class file back to the src folder and tried to remake the .java file but now I get errors like:

```
Error:(27, 27) java: cannot find symbol
 symbol:   class Route
 location: class si.um.opj.crisan.logic.Launcher
```

```
   Error:(55, 46) java: variable averageSpeed is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
```

for all methods and classes I use in Launcher.

Is there a possibility to get the old one back or how could I to fix these?

Thank you!

P.S. It`s my first question, please ask for details if things are not clear.

Comment: Please provide more code. Preferably java files for: `Main`, `Route` and `Launcher`. If you don't have them and you have only `.class` files you might need a decompiler. What IDE do you use?

Comment: From what I have observed, if I move the Launcher.class file in another package these errors appear. Do I still need to provide code? I don˙t really know what IDE, if JDK is one I think that`s what I am using.

Comment: The IDE is Intellij IDEA. :-P

Comment: `I have moved the .class file back to the src folder` why did you do this? Only sources must be placed in `src` directory. They then are compiled to .class files and placed into project compiler output directory.

Comment: From the `src`  I moved them in the other packages , so I reversed my moving.

Comment: A package import was missing from one of the classes. GG, thank you! :P